# python and mac-roman encoding issue

Tags: python, ios, objective-c

To be short, I have an iOS client, that turns NSData <90> into `NSString` with `NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding`, like below:

```
int v = 0x90;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&v length:1];
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:30];  //NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding
```

It turns `<90>`(NSData) into a string `ê`, which is `\xc3\xaa`;
like:

```
(lldb) mem read v
0x7b144210: 90 00 00 10 ab 44 b1 47 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  .....D.G........
0x7b144220: 90 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

(lldb) po data
<90>

(lldb) po s
ê
```

Now I want to simulate this logic on server side, using python, but I can't get the same result. It just turns `0x90` into `\x90`, and throw errors, even I specify `mac-roman` encoding like:

```
s = bytearray('\x90', encoding='mac-roman') // throw exception
```

I am no expert of python, and I don't know how to get it work. Can someone help? Thank in advance.

Comment: For those who saw this and seek answers, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40943154/python-how-to-encode-0x90-x90-as-macos-roman-encoding-to-xc3-xaa/40943203#40943191