# Python how to encode 0x90(\x90) as macOS Roman Encoding to \xc3\xaa

Tags: python, character-encoding

In python, if giving `0x90`(or `\x90`), how to encode it into a string as macOS Roman Encoding to `\xc3\xaa`, aka `ê`?

I tried `bytes('\x90').encode('mac-roman')`, it just throw errors.

`chr(0x90).encode('mac-roman')` is still the same failure.

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you final goal is, but as such it is encoded, so you **first** need to decode it, i mean,  *e.g.*

```
chr(0x90).decode('mac-roman')
```

You were almost there.

Comment: one more step is to encode it into utf-8. Thanks man, I just found my way before seeing yours!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, after searching two web pages: 
http://unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/APPLE/ROMAN.TXT
it shows:

> 0x90   0x00EA  # LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH CIRCUMFLEX

and http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ea/index.htm,:

> UTF-8 (hex)    0xC3 0xAA (c3aa)
>
> UTF-8 (binary) 11000011:10101010
>
> UTF-16 (hex)   0x00EA (00ea)

and trying decoding/encoding, I found it's:

`'\x90'.decode('mac-roman').encode('utf-8')`